# Playing a sound depending on the currently displayed flash card image

Tags: swift, ios, audio, cocoa

I've developed a fully working flash card app for kids. It has a `UIImageView` that cycles through 26 cards (abcs) via a gesture click and a music button that will play a sound for each image. Right now I have this 100% working, but the sound plays in an IF statement that has added an additional 400 lines of code.

How I load each card into the `UIImageView` from a gesture tap:

```
        // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
        if (gesture.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
            if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
                number = number % 26 + 1
            }
            else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "upper\(number)")
                number = number % 26 + 1
            }
```

Music button:

```
    if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card1")))! {
        do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: aSound))
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't load sound file")
        }
    }
    else if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card2")))! {
        do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: bSound))
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't load sound file")
        }
    }
    else if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card3")))! {
        do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: cSound))
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't load sound file")
        }
    }
```

I know I could set a sound array with the sound files in it, but how would I tie it back to the card? I can't set a tag property on an asset image, can I?

I'm looking for a way to shorten the current code I have.

Comment: What do `aSound` and `bSound` strings look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't determine the sound to play from the image displayed.  Instead you should use the same piece of information to set both the `image` `name` and the sound `path`.

Create a property of your `ViewController` to keep track of the card number that is being displayed:

```
var displayedCard = 1
```

and set it whenever you assign a new image to the imageView:

```
// if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
if (gesture.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
    if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
        displayedCard = number
        number = number % 26 + 1
    }
    else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && segControl2.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "upper\(number)")
        displayedCard = number
        number = number % 26 + 1
    }
```

Then use it to create the `String` you pass to `URL(fileWithPath:)`:

```
// create the soundPath using displayedCard
let letter = String(UnicodeScalar(96 + displayedCard)!)
let soundPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(letter)Sound.m4a", ofType:nil)!

do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath))
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
    print("Couldn't load sound file")
}
```

Comment: Sound strings look like this:
```let aSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "aSound.m4a", ofType:nil)!```

So when i set the displayedcard when loading it into the imageview, how would i then tell it that aSound belongs to card1, bSound to card2...etc?

Comment: See edit.  `letter` will be `a` to `z` when `displayedCard` is `1` to `26`.

Comment: WOW!  Worked with literally no edit.  Last question, i also have number flash cards 1-10, they are set as below:
```let num1Sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "num1.m4a", ofType:nil)!```

Would i just add the displayedcard like i did for the letter cards?  And then create different constants for letter and soundPath?

Comment: That's easier because we don't have to map a number to a letter. `let numSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "num\(displayedCard).m4a", ofType:nil)!`